# apach24+.htaccess+php error 500

Tags: php

Проблема такая, при переносе онлайн игры на другой хостинг возникает ошибки следующего рода. 
Сразу говорю ссылки все нормальные не битые. 
Игра разрабатывалась на php54.
Первое, включаю php52 на хостинге и php скрипты не работают частично т.к. не соответствие версий php и .htaccess работает исправно. 
Второе, включаю php53 на хостинге и php скрипты не работают частично но уже не так глобально тоже не соответствие версий php и .htaccess работает исправно. 
Третье, включаю php54 и выше на хостинге и .htaccess отваливается, пишется мол "Сайт (какой.такой) не может обработать скрипт ошибка 500" и вот тут я приплыл в лужу, чего только не делал все-равно не работает редирект. Стоит только понизить версию php как тут же редиректы работают исправно. В чем может быть подвох. На старом хостинге работает все нормально.
В логах только если сделать версию php56 то там мол функции для подключения к бд не соответствуют и говорит мол либо mysqli либо PDO использовать. Эт понятно что функции mysql не поддерживаются на php7. Спасибо каждому за ранее.

Comment: Вы же сами ответили на свой вопрос. В логах всё есть. Читайте и исправляйте. К нам то какой вопрос?

Comment: Прошу прощения за долгий ответ. Оч занят был. Странное дело было. Переустановил на vps linux с ubuntu на centos и все стало как и должно быть.